# Centos 7 Minimal VB network unreachable if I use WiFi?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, virtualbox

I am kind of banging my head here because i don't understand why a Virtualbox network that I set up with CentOS 7 using a bridged adapter works perfectly fine if I use an Ethernet cable, but if i use WiFi, the network is unreachable.

But my real problem is that I cannot find a way to make it work with WiFi.
During the installation process, when you choose a disk, keyboard and etc.
I can never establish a connection, wether I use NAT or bridged.

Is this an actual network configuration problem, or just bad installation process?

What I do with this VM is use it's SFTP connection on Windows so I can have a Linux distro to work on, it all works until i unplug that cable.

Comment: This is a common problem, as a Google search will reveal. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373059/virtualbox-fails-to-bridge-wifi-with-guest-os https://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/742739-VirtualBox-Bridged-Networking-(wifi)-not-working https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=84831

Comment: i suppose bridged connection will not always work, but the problem is that if i change to NAT i still can't get any network during installation.

Comment: It is a know limitation and vbox is full of bugs. Hyper V is a slightly better alternative, I prefer VmWare

Comment: That is a good tip, i might give one of those a try. I remember a while back, a friend of mine made wifi connection work on VB and also set up a DHCP server because bridged connection was not possible, the source of the problem could be something we might never find it, wether a firewall, a driver or just a virtualization of hardware, issue who knows. My knowledge of networking is on the script kiddie level so this is all confusing to me, thanks for the replies.

Comment: On this link the second note is very relevant: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Comment: which is basically saying the vb replaces the mac address in the destination header if it sees on the packet via DHCP and ARP.